# How to apply binary mask to remove background from skin lesion colour image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, background-foreground

the figure outputted just displays the binary mask image, however I am trying to get just the foreground of the coloured image, with the background being black.

```
    original = imread('originalImage.jpg');
    binaryImage = imread('binaryImage.png');



    mask = cat(3,binaryImage, binaryImage, binaryImage);
    output = mask.*original;
    figure,imshow(output);
```

[the binary mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Oitn.png)
[The original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1a6O.jpg)

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue is that `binary` is an image with values of 0 for background and 255 for foreground. Multiplying a color image with values in the range [0,255] by such a mask leads to overflow. Since the input images are uint8, overflow leads to values of 255. Thus, everywhere where the mask is white, you get white colors.

The solution is to convert the images to double:

```
output = double(mask)/255 .* double(original)/255;
```

or to truly binarize the mask image:

```
output = (mask>0) .* original;
```

Comment: When I load the binary image attached to the post, I get a logical image.